# how to save name of sheet tab export c#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, export-to-excel, excel-interop

i have following code how to save with sheetname  excel file please see below image and code, i want to add invoice no but its show error

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
// app.Visible = true;
app.Workbooks.Add(@"E:\Excel Single Sheet\Invoice-INV68.xls");
app.Workbooks.Add(@"E:\Excel Single Sheet\Invoice-INV67.xls");
string path = @"E:\E:\Excel Single Sheet\New folder\";
int InvoiceNo = 221;
for (int i = 2; i <= app.Workbooks.Count; i++)
{
    InvoiceNo++;
    for (int j = 1; j <= app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets.Count; j++)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = app.Workbooks[i].Worksheets[j];
        ws.Copy(app.Workbooks[1].Worksheets[1] + InvoiceNo);
    }
}
app.Save();
```

[image]

Comment: OK, so where have you tried to name it? you dont show any code for that.

Comment: You want to name the worksheet while exporting or read the name of existing worksheet, not understood?

Comment: If you want to name the worksheet while exporting,try worksheet.Name = "sheetName";

Comment: how to enter name i don't want to sheet1 sheet2 name